# How can I know the intervals of increase and decrease of a function?

Tags: calculus, functions

I mean, how can I know the intervals of increase and decrease of a composite function without seeing the graphic and just having the functions that form the composite function? Because I have some problems when both of the functions are piecewise functions.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are increasing when the first derivative is positive and decreasing when their first derivative is negative.